# I want to join two table with query builder in laravel

Tags: laravel, mysqli, inner-join, laravel-query-builder

I have Two table T1 and T2.
T2 is Making From T1.
T1 table:

```
      ID    Country Name
      1         Bangaldesh
      2        India
      3        USA
      4        UK
```

T2 table making from T1 ID

```
      ID    From T1 table C1    From T1 table C2
       1    1(Bangladesh)          2(India)
       2       2(India)            3(USA)
       3     2(India)             1(Bangladesh)
       4     2(India)             1(Bangladesh)
```

How can i Joining now Two Table for laravel query builder?
I need to show country name by ID
Thanks for Advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Check the documentation on joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins).

```php
DB::table('T2')->join('T1', 'T1.id', '=', 'T2.id_column')->get();
```

Assuming that the column in T2 that has the T1 id is called id_column.